# Why is the backup image size limited to 2088958MB?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, backup

I wanted to make a backup image of my drive with the windows 7 (x64) backup tool. I deselected any file-based backup options as I just wanted a full image (i.e. system reserved + C partition). I got the following error:

[image: myerror]

Then I tried using the free AOMEI onekey tool and it *also* said the drive was too big. My destination is a second drive (`D:`) which is empty and is formatted with ntfs. Partition sizes are:

- boot reserved: 100MB
- C: 2047.9GB (MBR)
- D: 5403GB (GPT)

Why is this limit and what is a fix for it (other than shrinking the C partition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Windows backup uses a variable size VHD file as its container.

A variable sized VHD (Dynamic VHD) is limited to 2088958MB.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dc9d9778-2c4c-4320-87e9-3e13597c84a4/volumes-larger-than-2088958-megabytes-cannot-be-protected-in-windows-server-2012?forum=windowsbackup)

You can either selectively backup only 2TB - 2MB (which is where the above number comes from) of data, or use a different backup scheme.

Alternatively, you can capture the filesystem in a compressed wim, hopfully reducing it's size somewhat. The Windows tools to do this are DISM or ImageX. The autoit guys made a nice GUI for ImageX called gImageX. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/gimagex/

Comment: And here's a source backing up the VHD statement. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dc9d9778-2c4c-4320-87e9-3e13597c84a4/volumes-larger-than-2088958-megabytes-cannot-be-protected-in-windows-server-2012?forum=windowsbackup

Comment: Yes a WIM should be a good workaround, **if** the restore utility supports it. But a WIM (regardless of compression) is a file-based image, not a sector-based image, making it *a bit* less attractive as a full backup.